# 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I've the following text in an html document:

```
<a href="#">�'ам интересна информация</a>
```

and I'm using the following expression for extracting the text:

```
row.xpath("string(./td[@class='col2 td-tags']/h3/a/text())")
```

This expression works fine for simple english, but for the above string it throws this error:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 6):

In HTML, &#xxx does NOT specify a byte in the document encoding; it's ALWAYS a unicode codepoint.

Thus, you can't put UTF-8 into an HTML like that.

Answer (score 2):

What encoding is the document in? What character starts the text in the `<a>`? It might be an invalid UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

I first decoded the page contents (which included the string `<a href="#">�'ам интересна информация</a>`) to replace any not convertible strings to question mark and it worked!

i.e. `page_contents_string = page_contents_string.decode("utf-8", "replace")`