# How to convert to unicode in python the following text?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I'm trying the following code on Python interactive shell:

```
>> unicode("�'ам интересна информация")
```

It's giving me the following error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I properly convert this string to Unicode without loosing any information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd maybe assume it's UTF-8 .. google translate says its Bulgarian, which is commonly encoded with `('iso_8859_5')` but that just makes a horrible mess when I try it.

What I'm doing is putting the byte string in a normal (non-unicode) string like this:

```
s = "�'ам интересна информация"
```

The first letter has the byte value:

```
>>> s[0]
'\xef'
>>> ord(s[0])
239
```

then trying to 'decode it to different coding schemes:

```
>>> from encodings import aliases
>>> print(aliases.aliases.keys())
>>> print s.decode('latin4')
īŋŊ'Đ°Đŧ Đ¸ĐŊŅĐĩŅĐĩŅĐŊĐ° Đ¸ĐŊŅĐžŅĐŧĐ°ŅĐ¸Ņ
>>> print s.decode('iso_8859_5')
яПН'аАаМ аИаНбаЕбаЕбаНаА аИаНбаОбаМаАбаИб
>>> print s.decode('utf_16')
뿯➽냐볐퀠킸톽킂통킀통킁킽₰룐뷐蓑뻐胑볐냐蛑룐近
>>> print s.decode('utf_8')
�'ам интересна информация
```

So the best I can come up with for your answer is:

> How can I properly convert this string to Unicode without loosing any information?

```
>>> uniVersion = "�'ам интересна информация".decode('utf-8')
>>> print uniVersion
�'ам интересна информация
```

Like the @Joey said, what you have is just a string of bytes, you can't really convert it into unicode without knowing what encoding it is already in.

The code you were trying wouldn't work because it defaults to assuming the data is in ascii 7 bit encoding. You could tweak it a bit:

```
>>> uniVersion = unicode("�'ам интересна информация", 'utf-8')
```

There you're just telling the unicode function, these bytes are encoded in utf-8 format.

The '�' symbol is used when the font doesn't have a representation for that character.

I would expect it's not really supposed to be part of the byte stream, or it got corrupted at some point, or possibly there's some more bytes in front of it missing that would give it more meaning.

Please feel free to ask for any clarifications in the comments.

Comment: You explained the answer quite well. Actually, I'm parsing and extracting this text from an html page. It parses other text properly but for this text, I'm getting error: `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte`. So, as you said, the first charter is causing some issues. But I don't know how to resolve. Plz plz check my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173255/utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xd0-in-position-0-invalid-continuation-byte

Comment: Have a look at the http headers to find out what the encoding on the page is. If it's showing those � symbols on the page, I'll bet that whoever configured their web server has the encoding set wrong. I'm suspecting the server is reporting utf-8 but the actual data presented is some other encoding. Can you just keep things in normal strings ? just treat them as byte strings ?

Comment: I used `"�'ам интересна информация".decode("utf-8", "replace")` to replace any not convertible strings to question mark and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Prefix the string with `u`:

```
u"�'ам интересна информация"
```

What you have there is just a bunch of binary data (i.e. a byte 'string'). You have to know the encoding to read it correctly in any case.